# Updating 2 tables in same order by 2 different process yield deadlock

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, service-broker

For some reason, we have multiple processes that get a request to update some tables (legacy code).

Let's say we have 2 process that simultaneously updating MyTable1 and MyTable2 in a transaction.

```
UPDATE MyTable1 SET ... WHERE Id=@p

UPDATE MyTable2 SET ... WHERE Id=@p
```

We have PK in Id column. Both processes are updating the above tables in same order as above. I am just trying to understand why we have deadlock in this case, as if one process update MyTable1 then row get locked and second process will be in waiting state, no?

Here is deadlock log,

```
<event name="xml_deadlock_report" package="sqlserver" timestamp="2023-07-05T06:28:23.146Z">
  <data name="xml_report">
    <type name="xml" package="package0" />
    <value>
      <deadlock>
        <victim-list>
          <victimProcess id="process238f3a7d088" />
          <victimProcess id="process238f77d48c8" />
        </victim-list>
        <process-list>
          <process id="process238f3a7d088" taskpriority="0" logused="440" waitresource="KEY: 11:72057594053263360 (a0c936a3c965)" waittime="4526" ownerId="126612753" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2023-07-04T23:28:18.463" XDES="0x238b9adc420" lockMode="X" schedulerid="1" kpid="7888" status="suspended" spid="98" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2023-07-04T23:28:18.610" lastbatchcompleted="2023-07-04T23:28:18.597" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.597" clientapp="Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="106-161-178-68" hostpid="5172" loginname="myuser" isolationlevel="repeatable read (3)" xactid="126612753" currentdb="11" currentdbname="MyDatabase" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
            <executionStack>
              <frame procname="adhoc" line="2" stmtstart="312" stmtend="826" sqlhandle="0x020000001a4a99011aeb41e53b61b0a4c7d0e6b18913364b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
              <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>
(@p1 int,@p0 int)SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [MyTable1] SET [MyColumn1] = @p0
WHERE [Id] = @p1;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

   </inputbuf>
          </process>
          <process id="process238f77d48c8" taskpriority="0" logused="440" waitresource="KEY: 11:72057594050052096 (59855d342c69)" waittime="4474" ownerId="126612775" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2023-07-04T23:28:18.600" XDES="0x238d9194420" lockMode="X" schedulerid="2" kpid="14064" status="suspended" spid="102" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2023-07-04T23:28:18.660" lastbatchcompleted="2023-07-04T23:28:18.653" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.653" clientapp="Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="106-161-178-68" hostpid="5172" loginname="myuser" isolationlevel="repeatable read (3)" xactid="126612775" currentdb="11" currentdbname="MyDatabase" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
            <executionStack>
              <frame procname="adhoc" line="2" stmtstart="216" stmtend="620" sqlhandle="0x0200000060f56a2965d4fcee92f09331f02e9231d62a2c880000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
              <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>
(@p1 int,@p0 int)SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [MyTable2] SET [MyColumn1] = @p0
WHERE [Id] = @p1;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

   </inputbuf>
          </process>
          <process id="process2388ae6a4e8" taskpriority="0" logused="440" waitresource="KEY: 11:72057594050052096 (59855d342c69)" waittime="4473" ownerId="126612776" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2023-07-04T23:28:18.600" XDES="0x238cde10420" lockMode="U" schedulerid="2" kpid="6456" status="suspended" spid="97" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2023-07-04T23:28:18.660" lastbatchcompleted="2023-07-04T23:28:18.653" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.653" clientapp="Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="106-161-178-68" hostpid="5172" loginname="myuser" isolationlevel="repeatable read (3)" xactid="126612776" currentdb="11" currentdbname="MyDatabase" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
            <executionStack>
              <frame procname="adhoc" line="2" stmtstart="216" stmtend="620" sqlhandle="0x0200000060f56a2965d4fcee92f09331f02e9231d62a2c880000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
              <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>
(@p1 int,@p0 int)SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [MyTable2] SET [MyColumn1] = @p0
WHERE [Id] = @p1;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

   </inputbuf>
          </process>
          <process id="process238f45b3468" taskpriority="0" logused="440" waitresource="KEY: 11:72057594053263360 (a0c936a3c965)" waittime="4550" ownerId="126612760" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2023-07-04T23:28:18.530" XDES="0x238c2dfc420" lockMode="X" schedulerid="2" kpid="12584" status="suspended" spid="99" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2023-07-04T23:28:18.587" lastbatchcompleted="2023-07-04T23:28:18.583" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.583" clientapp="Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="106-161-178-68" hostpid="5172" loginname="myuser" isolationlevel="repeatable read (3)" xactid="126612760" currentdb="11" currentdbname="MyDatabase" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
            <executionStack>
              <frame procname="adhoc" line="2" stmtstart="312" stmtend="826" sqlhandle="0x020000001a4a99011aeb41e53b61b0a4c7d0e6b18913364b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
              <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>
(@p1 int,@p0 int)SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [MyTable1] SET [MyColumn1] = @p0
WHERE [Id] = @p1;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

   </inputbuf>
          </process>
        </process-list>
        <resource-list>
          <keylock hobtid="72057594053263360" dbid="11" objectname="MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable1" indexname="PK_MyTable1" id="lock238f172bb00" mode="S" associatedObjectId="72057594053263360">
            <owner-list>
              <owner id="process238f45b3468" mode="S" />
              <owner id="process238f45b3468" mode="X" requestType="convert" />
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
              <waiter id="process238f3a7d088" mode="X" requestType="convert" />
            </waiter-list>
          </keylock>
          <keylock hobtid="72057594050052096" dbid="11" objectname="MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable2" indexname="PK_MyTable2" id="lock2389c487780" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594050052096">
            <owner-list>
              <owner id="process2388ae6a4e8" mode="S" />
              <owner id="process2388ae6a4e8" mode="U" requestType="convert" />
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
              <waiter id="process238f77d48c8" mode="X" requestType="convert" />
            </waiter-list>
          </keylock>
          <keylock hobtid="72057594050052096" dbid="11" objectname="MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable2" indexname="PK_MyTable2" id="lock2389c487780" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594050052096">
            <owner-list>
              <owner id="process238f77d48c8" mode="U" />
              <owner id="process238f77d48c8" mode="X" requestType="convert" />
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
              <waiter id="process2388ae6a4e8" mode="U" requestType="convert" />
            </waiter-list>
          </keylock>
          <keylock hobtid="72057594053263360" dbid="11" objectname="MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable1" indexname="PK_MyTable1" id="lock238f172bb00" mode="S" associatedObjectId="72057594053263360">
            <owner-list>
              <owner id="process238f3a7d088" mode="S" />
              <owner id="process238f3a7d088" mode="X" requestType="convert" />
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
              <waiter id="process238f45b3468" mode="X" requestType="convert" />
            </waiter-list>
          </keylock>
        </resource-list>
      </deadlock>
    </value>
  </data>
</event>
```

My Code is simple as that,

```
    public class MyConsumer : IConsumer<MyModel>
    {
        private readonly MyService _myService;

        public AddUpdateHubLinkConsumer(MyService myService)
        {
            _myService= myService;
        }
        public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<MyModel> context)
        {
            await _myService.SaveMyChanges(context.Message);

        }
    }

    public class MyService
    {
        
        public async Task SaveMyChanges(MyModel model)
        {
            // My work there
            await myDbContext.SaveMyChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show the tables and index definitions, and please share the execution plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan I must say, something looks weird about this deadlock graph: I've never seen two separate chains in a single graph. Is this the actual XDL, unchanged except for the names?

Comment: @Charlieface https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1TaLkXt2

Comment: That's for a `SELECT` not for these `UPDATE` queries. Please show the plans for the real queries, and if there is an overall ransaction using `BEGIN TRAN` then please show the plans for the whole batch. Are you perhaps reading these rows elsewhere in the traansaction?

Comment: We have ORM that runs the above queries.

Comment: You can use [`EXEC sp_WhoIsActive @get_plans = 1;`](http://whoisactive.com) or similar tools to get the query plan as the ORM is executing the query. You can also use Query Store to capture the plan, and recall it after it's done executing.

Comment: How is it relevant that an ORM is creating these queries? The fact is the plan you showed does not match the deadlock graph. Please show the *real* plan, and if you are using a transaction (even one initiated on the client-side) please show the plans for all queries in the same transaction.

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJf2inQKh 
@J.D. will try when this again when this happen.

Comment: I honestly can't see any way these can deadlock, they are single-row lookups on an index. Can we verify something: are these two `UPDATE` queries being run in an outer transaction or not? And what isolation level is being used? Because the pattern of locking doesn't match what would normally be seen in a single `UPDATE` statement when `READ COMMITTED` is being used. You would normally expect a U lock immediately if it was a single-row index seek, not an S lock being upgraded to X lock.

Comment: @Charlieface specifically I don't have transaction anywhere. But ORM do use when we call `SaveChangesAsync` which we call unit of work and this code invoked by RabbitMQ consumer(`MassTransit.IConsumer`). So it is possible that broker have transaction and ORM have nested transaction. See my update in question.

Comment: Look like its nested transation as IConsumer is wrapped inside the transaction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75152971/masstransit-transactional-outbox-isolation-level-per-consumer

Comment: OK so what is `// My work there` what are you actually doing? Can you run a trace on either the client application or the server to see what SQL is actually being executed?

Comment: See 2 update statements in question. This is what I am doing here.

Comment: @Charlieface, the deadlock graph shows `REPEATABLE READ` transaction isolation level.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thanks. Then I suspect there are other `SELECT` statements being run in the same transaction which do not have `UPDLOCK` hints.